# Lotus notes text field width on web

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus-domino

I would like to increase width of lotus notes text field on web, I have tried

```
width="48"
```

On html tab of the field and put there in style tag but that is not working.

Basically I am having comment field which wherein I would like to increase width of the field so user can see enter long text instead of typing and getting moved.

P.s I know richtext field which can have cols and rows property but I dont need rich text field. I just need simple text field.

Comment: I think you need to add px for pixels, so width="48px"

Comment: even that does not work. :(

Comment: What does the HTML output look like in the browser?

Comment: <input name="Comment1" value="" style="width=&quot;48px&quot;"></td>

Comment: change to width=48px (so without the quotes)

Comment: No it did not work as well. <input name="Comment1" value="" style="width=100px;">

Comment: Argh, use colon and not equals sign: width:48px

Comment: that did the trick,thanks it worked.

Comment: Great. I added it as an answer

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use colon and not an equals sign and add px. So do this instead:

```
width:48px;
```